# Identifying parts within a link and reformat them in the embed

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to create command that identifies the sitename and the username from the link. For example using `!link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Example`, `!link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Contributions/Example`, or `!link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_talk:Example` would create an embed of

```
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setColor('#bf00ff')
.addTitle(`en.wikipedia.org`, [Wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page))
.addField(`User info of Example`, `[Userpage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Example) | [User_talk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_talk:Example) | [Logs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Log/Example) | [User groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:UserRights/Example) | [User contributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Contributions/Example) | [BlockLog](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Log/block&page=User:Example)
message.channel.send(embed)
```

Also, if the link doesn't have `User:`, `Special:Contributions/`, or `User_talk:`, as well as the sitename (e.g. `en.wikipedia.org`), and the username within it, then create an error message.

If the link contains `?useskin=monobook`, `?useskin=vector`, `?useskin=modern`, or `?useskin=apex`, which is after the username, ignore those part in the link. For example, `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_talk:Example?useskin=vector` should be interpreted as `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_talk:Example`, and the username should also be interpreted as `Example`, not `Example?useskin=vector`

How could I accomplish that?

Comment: Does the url have to have *all* of those elements, or only one?

Comment: Yes ,the url in the command has to have the sitename with /wiki (such examples are `en.wikipedia.org/wiki`, `www.mediawiki.org/wiki`, `en.wiktionary.org/wiki`, etc.). The url of the wiki can be any of them, as long as it has the `/wiki` after the sitename. It also have to have the username in that same link. For example, username in the link of `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Contributions/Example` is Example.